# How to Sign Bitcoin Transaction from two or more children wallet in HD wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, bitcoin-cli, signrawtransaction

How can I handle a situation where I have bitcoin on two or more different wallets with a single phrase, how can I sign the two transactions to a friend.

Example:
I have 2BTC in a wallet address that is at path m/44'/0'/0'/0'/0
I also have 1BTC in another wallet address that is at path m/44'/0'/0'/0'/1

How can I sign the 3BTC to a friend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If by **wallet** you mean address, there is no problem. You can create a 3 BTC transaction and submit it. The wallet itself will handle joining different coins in different addresses to make a single 3 BTC coin. But if you really have 2 coins in two completely separate wallets, you can send one of your coins to another wallet, in order to put both coins in a same wallet. Then you're able to create a 3 BTC transaction.